# Increase number of login attempts per user or per role in Drupal

Tags: security, drupal, drupal-6, authentication

Is it possible to increase number of login attempts before blocking an account for a certain user or role in Drupal? (not for all users)
Or even never block a certain user regardless of number of login failures?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Does Drupal 6 lockout accounts after a certain number of failures? Everything I'm reading indicates that this is a Drupal 7 feature. Anyway...*

It looks the [Login Security](http://drupal.org/project/login_security) module would allow you to customize how users get blocked. You may check out the temporarily blocked feature.

> Enabling this module, a site administrator may limit the number of invalid login attempts before blocking accounts, or denying access by IP address, temporarily or permanently. A set of notifications may help the site administrator to know when something is happening with the login form of their site: password and account guessing, bruteforce login attempts or just unexpected behaviour with the login operation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However Login Security module allows to configure number of login failures for all users only. I need to increase this number for a certain user or role. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in Drupal 6 then you probably have a module performing the blocking of accounts, because this isn't in Drupal 6 core.

It is in Drupal 7 however.

If you are using Drupal 6, then you need to find out which module is doing the blocking.

If you are using Drupal 7 you can install the flood_control module to expose the variables around blocking.
http://drupal.org/project/flood_control

Comment: I use Drupal 6. Right now I'm checking out Login Security module which was suggested in a previous answer.

Comment: For Drupal 6 Login Security module is responsible for blocking. It is quite useful, I want to keep it, but not flexible enough (allows to configure number of login failures for all users only).

Answer (score 0):

There is always an option to hardcode a user id or role id inside of login_security.module
There is a function  login_user_block_user_name($variables) in login_security.module responsible for blocking users.
Adding a condition if($variables['uid']!=user_id_not_to_block) or something like that can work.
However hardcoding isn't the best solution.